# Drop the dragged element at specific location in vuejs using jsPlumb

Tags: drag-and-drop, vuejs2, jsplumb

I'm working on drag and drop requirement in **vuejs** using **jsPlumb**. I'm able to drag and drop but the problem is while dropping the element is not dropping at the exact position where I'm dropping instead it will take an initial position (top-left corner) of the div.

The html code in drag.vue :

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <div draggable="true" id="drag1" class="Source" @dragstart="start" @dragend="end">drag-1</div>
  <div droppable="true" @dragover.prevent @drop="drop" id="drop-location">
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
#drag1{
position:relative;
}
#drop-location{
position: relative;
height:400px;
width : 100%;
background-color: grey;
}
.Source { 
    background-color: #EEEEEF;
    border: 1px solid #346789;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #AAAAAA;
    color: black;
    min-height: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 5em;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:2%;
}
```

The script code:

```
 export default {
  data (){
    return{
    id1: 0,
    htmlBase: 'drop-location',
    id2: ''
   }
 },
methods: {
        start: function(event) {this.dragEl = event.target;},
        end: function(event) { this.dragEl = undefined;  },
        drop: function(event, ui) {

        this.id1++
        this.id2 = event.currentTarget.id + this.id1;

        $('<div class=" Source node" id="' + this.id2 +'" data-nodetype="source">').appendTo('#'+ this.htmlBase).html($(("#drag1"))[0].innerHTML);

             jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
             jsPlumb.draggable(this.id2, {
               appendTo: "body",
                cursor: "pointer",
                containment:"drop-location",
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: "invalid",
                containment: 'parent'
            });
       }
  }
}
```

So how can drop the element at a specific location? Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

did you check  [JsPlumb Docs on Vue2 Integration?](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/docs/toolkit/vue2-integration.html)

I think you can try with adding template option to your component:

```
             jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
             jsPlumb.draggable(this.id2, {
               appendTo: "body",
                cursor: "pointer",
                containment:"drop-location",
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: "invalid",
                containment: 'parent',
                template:'<ul><li v-for="node in nodeTypes" :data-type="type"></li></ul>',
            });
```